# Can not start NetworkManager, Bus error

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager

I have tried to start NetworkManager by running the command

> sudo systemctl start NetworkManager

but it gives me the following error:

```
 Job for NetworkManager.service failed because a fatal signal was delivered causing the control process to dumb core
See "systemctl status NetworkManager.service" and "journal -xe" for details.
```

Now when I run

> systemctl status NetworkManager.service

I got a strange error, me for myself never experience before:

```
Active: failed (Result: core-dumb)
Process: 28722 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon (code=dumbed, signal=BUS)
MainPID:28772(code=dumbed, signal=BUS)
```

What could have possible gone wrong and how can I fix such problem?

Comment: Look at my AskUbuntu profile for hints about looking at logs with `journalctl`, particularly the `jcnet` alias. When I get back home, I'll expand.

Comment: Look at the logs with `sudo journalctl -b 0 _SYSTEMD_UNIT=NetworkManager.service`